# Save password protected Excel file to XML in C# (I know the password)

Tags: c#, excel, passwords, xls

I have a password protected XLS (the data is not protected the the adding of columns is disabled). This is the code:

```
 _excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            _excelApp.Visible = false;

            //opens
            workBook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(InputDirectory + CharacterFileName,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            workBook.Password = "0000";

            //save
            workBook.SaveAs(OutputDirectoryFileName, XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet,
                "0000", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

The password is "0000". How can I make this code work? I tried setting the password but it refuses to save as XML (ERROR)

The error is in french since I'm using french .NET " Le classeur que vous essayez d'enregistrer est protégé par mot de passe. Les classeurs protégés par mot de passe ne peuvent pas être enregistrés dans une feuille de calcul XML. Pour enregistrer ce fichier sous forme de feuille de calcul XML, vous devez d'abord supprimer le mot de passe."

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so what I had to do is this:

```
//unprotect the workbook
ExcelHelperWorkbook.Unprotect(password);

//unprotect the first worksheet
((Worksheet)ExcelHelperWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1)).Unprotect(password);
```

Then I can run the SaveAs :)

Answer (score 1):

The error translated is:

"The workbook you are trying to record is protected by password. Folders protected by a password can not be stored in an XML Spreadsheet. To save this file as an XML spreadsheet, you must first remove the password." (Go Google translate!)

So this is by design, so the only way forward is to remove the password, and then save it.

Comment: Any way to automate that in C# ?

Comment: Look at this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9864c1ab-3efe-4d7c-8ff3-ca8858af3c22/